# What is the latest version of .Net FrameWork and Visual studio

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to know about the latest .net framework and visual studio versions avalilable in the market.

Comment: I don't consider a two-year release cycle "pretty fast".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.Net 3.5 SP1 and Visual Studio 2008 SP1 are the current versions that are released.

.Net 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 are currently in beta release and are expected sometime in Q1 of 2010 for full release

Comment: +1 for the beta info. Whether indeed it's Q1 2020, we'll see about that :P

Comment: It better not be ... I'm already working in 2010 and need the full release to happen soon so that I can go to production with what I'm working on in 4.0

Comment: Thank you Mr.Chris Nicol for response.

Comment: i have a doubt in 2008 version of visula studio is there any option for silverlight

Comment: Yes there is support for Silverlight in Visual Studio 2008

Comment: ok, why i am asking like this is, present i am working on 2.0 Frame work and 2005 visual studio

Comment: Yup ... you should consider looking at 2008, it's stable and a huge improvement over 2005 (in my opinion)

Comment: Note that Visual Studio 2008 SP1 is the latest released VS version.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of the .NET Framework is 4.6. Here are some of its new features:

- Async model binding
- Roslyn CodeDOM compilers
- HTTP/2 support

The newest version of Visual Studio is  Visual Studio 2015 RC.Please check the link: https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-vs

And the version of Visual Studio available in market is Visual Studio 2013 and .net Framework 4.5